# Woocommerce - internal server error: Notice: id was called incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My site has a problem. On checkout I get the Internal server error. I have read almost all the solutions provided on forums and even on this forum but none proved to solve this problem. Here is the error log below.

> Notice: id was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require(‘wp-blog-header.php’), require_once(‘wp-includes/template-loader.php’), include(‘/themes/astra/page.php’), astra_content_page_loop, do_action(‘astra_content_page_loop’), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, Astra_Loop->loop_markup_page, Astra_Loop->loop_markup, do_action(‘astra_page_template_parts_content’), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, Astra_Loop->template_parts_page, get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require(‘/themes/astra/template-parts/content-page.php’), the_content, apply_filters(‘the_content’), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, WC_Shortcodes::checkout, WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper, call_user_func, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::order_received, wc_get_template, include(‘/plugins/woocommerce/templates/ch in /home/newsvlup/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4161

Comment: Make sure your wordpress and woocommerce is updated also switch with default theme and check if still same error is coming?

Comment: Make sure that WordPress (and WooCommerce) are updated. WooCommerce deprecates certain function from time to time and you most likely encountered one of such functions.

Comment: I updated wordpress and woocommerce and its still the same thing. Dont know what I was missing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because of Woocommerce deprecated some methods in the new version, but your existing code in plugins or theme are using the old methods to get the cart data that’s why you are receiving this notice.

Best way to ignore this type of notices is to check all the plugins and theme with the new version of the WooCommerce before making live.

I hope this finds you well with your concern.

Comment: My themes and plugins are updated. Is there a code I can use to override this issue so i stop getting the Internal server error problem and which file do i update it. kindly help.

Comment: Are you updated wp-includes folder with new version of wordpress??

Comment: Yes they are updated. I disabled all plugins, changed theme and the error persist. Is there something I can do to fix this. please.

Comment: clear the browser cache and refresh the page. and then write the error here

Comment: WOW. Worked like magic. I just cleared cache now and it worked flawlessly. Thanks so much. I had to try to order from 3 different browsers to confirm this. Thank you.